Removing old wood stove chimney from garage
I want to remove this old chimney from my garage because it leaks when it rains and from snow melt in the winter.
Thinking I could attempt to just take the angle grinder and cut it and drop it in a few pieces from a ladder. Then hoping it will mostly just fall down through the hole and I can deal with it from below. Then to find a somewhat matching piece of roof to patch and tar over the hole.
Also unsure what exactly all the pieces are. I can't identify the purpose of the box at the bottom.
Any other ideas or took suggestions? Not a fan of being on the roof. Have some quotes to have it removed but rather save the money if I could.


This is a "do it however it works with the tools you have" scenario. There's not going to be much specific wisdom to share. The "box" is a thimble of sorts. It keeps heat from affecting the roof as it passes through.

Don't forget, you're going to have to remove 1 or 2 roofing panels that have holes through them and replace those, too. Otherwise you're going to get a lot of water in through the roof when it rains. You'll probably also have to replace the panels where the chimney braces are bolted down, as there are probably some big holes there. And your new green roof panels will be a much brighter green than the faded green of the existing roof. Someone might not like the patchwork quilt look and you may end up replacing this whole side of the roof...

The box at the bottom is just a spacer to keep the hot pipe off the roof.
Cut it up however you like really, there's no right way to do demo.  Use a harness thrown over the roof and tied off to something real, a fall from a roof can be life altering (or ending).
